# iOS WebRTC framework compiling not working the same as cocoa pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webrtc, chromium

The 'main' google webrtc library from cocoa pods is 
https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleWebRTC

I have found it to be different in subtle functionalities (REMB and simulcasting) than the gClient built framework with the webRTC repo.

The directions I've followed are these
[http://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/ios/\](http://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/ios/%5C)

My instinct is it's simply an argument issue when building the framework. Does anyone know what args google uses when compiling this?

Comment: Are you comparing the cocoa pods version and master?

Comment: cocoa pods with Master yes. I grabbed the most recent, tried a random head from July, then another from late september (if it were some subtle bug). Also just tried from the M75 branch. Each time I get the same strange issue. EVERYTHING works, if not more smoothly, except simulcasting...

Comment: @JohnLanzivision Did you find the solution by chance? I'm also trying to build latest webrtc framework for iOS with sender_encodings for transceiver (to implement simulcast).

Comment: My issue ended up being a problem with the max/min bitrates I specified on the peer connection. 
My solution was not specifying any min/max. I figured it out by turning on the webrtc logs and finding the bitrates it associated with each sub steam. Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't know the solution, but please don't use the cocoa pods! It hasn't been updated since October 2019 and has grave security vulnerabilities. [CVE-2020-6514](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2020-6514)

Project Zero was able to get a RCE with it you can read more [here](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2020/08/exploiting-android-messengers-part-1.html)

Comment: Good to know! Yeah we use our own framework from the latests release, thankgoodness. Have any ideas about who or where I could go to get the build args from?